# What is extension closure in triangulated categories?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

The term *extension closure* appears in some papers constructing t-structures on triangulated categories, for example in Section 1.2 of

*Bayer, Arend; Macrì, Emanuele; Toda, Yukinobu*, [**Bridgeland stability conditions on threefolds. I Bogomolov-Gieseker type inequalities**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S1056-3911-2013-00617-7), J. Algebr. Geom. 23, No. 1, 117-163 (2014). [ZBL1306.14005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1306.14005).

The text is roughly as follows. Let $X$ be a smooth projective $\mathbb{C}$-variety. Let $D^b(X)$ denote the derived category of bounded complexes of coherent sheaves. Let $\mathrm{Coh}(X)\subseteq D^b(X)$ denote the heart of the natural t-structure. Given a torsion pair $\mathcal{T},\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathrm{Coh}(X)$, we want to consider a tilting heart
$$\langle \mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}\rangle\subseteq D^b(X)$$
which is called the *extension closure*. Here are my questions

1. What is $\langle \mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}\rangle$? What are the objects?
2. What are extensions in $D^b(X)$? I know short exact sequences in $D^b(X)$ split and thus I do not believe extensions here mean short exact sequences as for abelian categories.
3. Does the order matter? Does $\langle \mathcal{T},\mathcal{F}[1]\rangle=\langle \mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}\rangle$?

Comment: For your second question, extensions of $(Z,X)$ are objects $Y$ that fit into a triangle $$X \to Y \to Z \to \Sigma X$$ for the third I think the orders matters!

Comment: I’ve checked some references and the $\langle \ast \rangle$ notation seems to be the triangulated category generated by both things (but it could be the extriangulated) if this is it the order would not matter

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Thanks. The collection of objects seems to consist of extensions of objects of $\mathcal{T}\cup\mathcal{F}[1]$, extensions of such extensions, and extensions of such ext of exts, etc.

Comment: Then it’s the extriangulated category $\langle \mathcal{F}[1] , \mathcal{T} \rangle$ (smallest full subcategory stable by extensions) it is not triangulated !It should also be stable by direct factors and addition. In this case the order does not matter!

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace For what I am concerned, the subcategory $\langle\mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}\rangle$ should be Abelian, and it contains $\mathcal{F}[1]$ and $\mathcal{T}$. So I think the order will not matter.

Comment: Yes I wrote too fast I corrected it though. It can be Abelian but I don’t know how to prove it. It may also be only exact and not abelian.

Comment: The category is abelian if $(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{F})$ is a torsion pair. This follows from the fact that one can define a t-structure on $D^b(X)$ such that $\langle \mathcal{F}[1], \mathcal{T} \rangle$ is its heart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote an Abelian category and consider its bounded derived category $D^b(\mathcal{A})$. In this case, there is a "standard" $t$-structure coming from truncation of complexes; its heart is $\mathcal{A}$ viewed as complexes with cohomology only in degree $0$.

Given a pair of full subcategories of $\mathcal{A}$ denoted $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{F}$, $(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{F})$ is a torsion pair if every object $X\in \mathcal{A}$ fits into an exact sequence $0 \to T\to X\to F\to 0$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{F}) = 0$.

With this information, we can perform a (right) *tilt* to get a new heart of a bounded $t$-structure on $D^b(\mathcal{A})$ defined to be the extension closure of $\mathcal{F}[1]$ and $\mathcal{T}$. An extension in a triangulated category of an object $X$ by an object $Y$ is a distinguished triangle $Y\to Z\to X$, and we also say that the object $Z$ is an extension of $X$ by $Y$.

There is another characterisation of $\langle \mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}\rangle$ as those $X\in D^b(\mathcal{A})$ with $H^{-1}_{\mathcal{A}}(X) \in \mathcal{F}$ and $H^0_{\mathcal{A}}(X) \in \mathcal{T}$. It is important to note that $\langle \mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}\rangle$ is not closed under application of the shift functor, and consequently is not a triangulated subcategory of $D^b(\mathcal{A})$.

I believe the role of the ordering $\langle \mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}\rangle$ is to emphasize that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{F}[1],\mathcal{T}) = 0$. Indeed, given $F\in \mathcal{F}$ and $T\in \mathcal{T}$, $\mathrm{Hom}(F[1],T) = \mathrm{Ext}^{-1}_{\mathcal{A}}(F,T) = 0$.

A short synopsis of some of these things can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0552.pdf) also in the context of Bridgeland Stability.